# How do you install Bitcoin Daemon using Yum package manager?

Tags: bitcoind, installation

I have a Centos setup with the Yum package manager. How do you install Bitcoin Daemon using Yum? Or is it even possible right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page has instruction on how to install Bitcoin using `yum`:

http://linux.ringingliberty.com/bitcoin/